# Delta-sigma DAC from Verilog to VHDL

Tags: audio, vhdl, verilog, dac

The code below implements a Delta-sigma DAC in Verilog, from a Xilinx application note and I want to write equivalent VHDL code. I don't know anything about Verilog and I'm beginner in VHDL so I had to make a lot of guesses and probably beginner errors (code below). I'm not sure the translation is correct can someone help please?

**Original Verilog**

```
`timescale 100 ps / 10 ps
`define MSBI 7

module dac(DACout, DACin, Clk, Reset);
output DACout;
reg DACout;
input [`MSBI:0] DACin;
input Clk;
input Reset;

reg [`MSBI+2:0] DeltaAdder;
reg [`MSBI+2:0] SigmaAdder;
reg [`MSBI+2:0] SigmaLatch;
reg [`MSBI+2:0] DeltaB;

always @(SigmaLatch) DeltaB = {SigmaLatch[`MSBI+2], SigmaLatch[`MSBI+2]} << (`MSBI+1);
always @(DACin or DeltaB) DeltaAdder = DACin + DeltaB;
always @(DeltaAdder or SigmaLatch) SigmaAdder = DeltaAdder + SigmaLatch;
always @(posedge Clk or posedge Reset)
begin
    if(Reset)
    begin
        SigmaLatch <= #1 1'bl << (`MSBI+1);
        DACout <= #1 1'b0;
    end
    else
    begin
        SigmaLatch <== #1 SigmaAdder;
        DACout <= #1 SigmaLatch[`MSBI+2];
    end
end
endmodule
```

**My try in VHDL:**

```
entity audio is
    generic(
        width  : integer := 8
    );
    port(
        reset  : in    std_logic;
        clock  : in    std_logic;
        dacin  : in    std_logic_vector(width-1 downto 0);
        dacout : out   std_logic
    );
end entity;

architecture behavioral of audio is
    signal deltaadder    : std_logic_vector(width+2 downto 0);
    signal sigmaadder    : std_logic_vector(width+2 downto 0);
    signal sigmalatch    : std_logic_vector(width+2 downto 0);
    signal deltafeedback : std_logic_vector(width+2 downto 0);
begin
    deltafeedback <= (sigmalatch(width+2), sigmalatch(width+2), others => '0');
    deltaadder <= dacin + deltafeedback;
    sigmaadder <= deltaadder + sigmalatch;

    process(clock, reset)
    begin
        if (reset = '1') then
            sigmalatch <= ('1', others => '0');
            dacout <= '0';
        elsif rising_edge(clock) then
            sigmalatch <= sigmaadder;
            dacout <= sigmalatch(width+2);
        end if;
    end process;
end architecture;
```

Comment: Have you tried simulating both the Verilog and VHDL and checking the output?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you're using ieee.std_logic_unsigned (or _arith) or both.

[Please don't do that](http://www.parallelpoints.com/node/3). Use `ieee.numeric_std.all` instead.

My Verilog is fairly non-existent, so I forget if Verilog defaults to signed or unsigned arithmetic... But whichever it is, make all your numerical signals into `signed` or `unsigned` types to match.

Your reset clause probably wants to read something like:

```
sigmalatch <= (width+1 => '1', others => '0');
```

and the deltafeedback update is something like:

```
deltafeedback(width+2 downto width+1) <= sigmalatch(width+2) & sigmalatch(width+2);
deltafeedback(width downto 0) <= (others => '0');
```

Finally, to match the Verilog, I think your `width` generic should be called `MSBI` and set to 7, (or change all your `width+2`s to `width+1`s to match your intention for the `width` generic)

Comment: Verilog arithmetic is unsigned by default, which is actually the opposite of what it should be :-)

Answer (score 2):

If you are simply interested in Delta-sigma DAC in VHDL, you may take a look at my implementation posted to [alt.sources](http://groups.google.com/group/alt.sources/msg/28fbd9b917c78fd7) (please select the "original message", save to a file and run "unshar" on it to get sources).

Wojtek